# Xamarin.Forms PCL cannot show image

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm learning Xamarin.Forms PCL. I want to load image on page, i tried to load image with uri, that's OK. But i add image into project, it's don't work.

```
<StackLayout Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <Image x:Name="img" Source="mario.jpg"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRotate" Clicked="btnRotate_Clicked" Text="Rotate" />
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't be `<Image x:Name="img" Source="mario.jpg"/>` ? You are missing a "m"

Comment: thanks #apineda! i tried this, but it's not work

Comment: Where are you trying to load the image from? I see 'mario.jpg' in both your PCL as well as your Android project. If you try to load it from the Android project: right-click the file, choose properties and check it the Build action is set to `AndroidResource`

Comment: i want to load from the Android project and IOS. i tried, but image not show

Answer (score 2):

> **You can not include dashes or spaces in image names for Android compatibility**

Rename your image from `piotr-chrobot-276746.jpg` to something else, like **piotrchrobot.jpg**

[image]

> https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/

Don't forget to set the **Build action** to **AndroidResource.**

[image]

Comment: Maybe, you can share a github repo to take a look :)

Comment: i see my folder with attribute read only, is this problem? and i tried to removed read only attribute but not success :(